# How to change day/date/year in sas?

Tags: statistics, sas

In my data lines, the data is 03/MAY/2012.
How can I make this data to 05/03/2012?
(Do not change data in data lines)
I don’t know how to do.

Comment: Are you reading in the date as a character or a date format? Please show your INPUT statement and any INFORMAT statements as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Use INFORMAT `DATE.` to specify how the data should be read in - so what format is the input in.
- Use FORMAT `MMDDYYS10.` to specify how the data should be displayed

```
data have;
informat date date.;
format date mmddyys10.;
input date;
cards;
03/May/2012
;;;;
run;
```